# SSL setup in Centos (.pem and .crt files)

Tags: ssl, https, apache2

I want to setup an SSL configuration on Apache. All I see in the web is that there should be some .key and .crt files. However, I have these files

```
# ls
fullchain.crt  private.pem
certificate.crt             order          public.pem
```

I tried the following configuration based on the explanation [here](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/install-ssl-certificate-on-apache-centos), However, by restarting **httpd** I get an error which says private key not found.

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/snadmin/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/snadmin/public.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/snadmin/fullchain.crt
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SSLCertificateKeyFile` must point to the *private* key, not the public one. See also the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatekeyfile).